# conditional expectations

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, conditioning

Hi i was wondering how to figure out the following

Suppose $y=x+e$ where e is an i.i.d error. Say $x \sim N(\mu,\sigma_1^2)$ and $e \sim N (0, \sigma_e^2)$ which means $y \sim N (\mu, \sigma_1^2+\sigma_e^2)$. I need to find the expected value of y, conditional on $y>\mu$. I know that the formula will be y multiplied by the normal pdf but what is the actual output. As in, i can set up the integral however i cannot calculate it. I know the answer will be ($\mu$+something) just dont know what that something is.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Conditioned on $\{Y > \mu\}$, the conditional density of $Y$ is just
$\frac{2}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-(y-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2){\mathbf 1}_{y>\mu}$ and
$$E[Y \mid Y > \mu] = \int_\mu^\infty y f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy 
= \int_0^\infty (\sigma x+\mu)\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-x^2/2)\,\mathrm dx$$
which can be split into the sum of two integrals. I hope that you can figure out
the value of one of the integrals without needing to actually do any 
integration, while for
the other integral, you need to reflect on the fact that 
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\exp(-x^2/2) = - x\exp(-x^2/2)$$ 
and whether this fact might help you in evaluating the integral.

Comment: Hi thanks for that dilip. I have a couple of questions,
1. This may be a stupid question but we are trying to integrate over y but have x in the expression. 
2. Is this a general formula? So suppose intead of u being the mean, the mean was u+c and i was trying to integrate from j to infinity (does this make sense?) basically i wanted to know if this is the general forumla.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance!

Comment: @user55405 `We are trying to integrate over ` $y$ `but have ` $x$ `in the expression.`  That was a typo on my part: I have now fixed it. The second integral on the first displayed equation is with respect to $x$, not $y$, and the second integral is the result of making a change of variables: substituting $\sigma x + \mu$ for $y$ in the first integral.

Answer (score 1):

If $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then
$$
{\rm E}[Y\mid Y>\mu]=\frac{1}{P(Y>\mu)}{\rm E}[Y\mathbf{1}_{Y>\mu}].
$$
That is,
$$
2{\rm E}[Y\mid Y>\mu]=\sigma{\rm E}[Z\mathbf{1}_{Z>0}]+\mu {\rm E}[\mathbf{1}_{Z>0}]=\sigma {\rm E}[Z\mathbf{1}_{Z>0}]+\frac12\mu,
$$
where 
$$
Z=\frac{1}{\sigma}(Y-\mu)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1).
$$